# Conflict between amscd and unicode-math

Tags: amsmath, unicode-math

After switching to the unicode-math package, the amscd package for commutative diagrams doesn't work anymore. I do not get error messages, but the symbols like @ and < are displayed in the output.

I attach an almost minimal example, which worked before.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amscd}
\newcommand\xbf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\fg[1]{#1}
\newcommand\obf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\R{{R}}
\begin{document}
Diagram:
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{CD}
    \obf{\omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} @<\xbf{Ad}_{\xbf{B}}<< \obf{\Omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} \\
    @A\hat{\ }AA @AA\hat{\ }A\\
    \fg{\omega}=\xbf{B}\fg{\Omega} \in\R^3 @<\xbf{B}<< \fg{\Omega}\in \R^3
  \end{CD}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Added the tag `amsmath` since `amscd` a component of that package.

Answer (score 4):

The `amscd` package performs

```
\mathcode`@="8000
```

in order to make `@` math active. It also executes `\CDat` when starting a `CD` environment, where `\CDat` is defined by

```
\gdef\CDat{\let @=\Iat}
```

in a context where `@` is active. It's not important to know what `\Iat` is, just that it is essential that `@` is math active and has the meaning `\Iat` during processing of the `CD` environment.

Unfortunately, the `unicode-math` normalizes math codes at `\begin{document}`, so the setting of the math code of `@` is forgotten.

You can actually improve the definition of the `CD` environment to become independent of surrounding conditions (which should have been done also by the `amscd` package, but there are historical reasons for it not to).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\CDat{\let~\Iat\mathcode`@="8000\relax}%
}

\newcommand\xbf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\fg[1]{#1}
\newcommand\obf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\R{{R}}

\begin{document}
Diagram:
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{CD}
    \obf{\omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} @<\xbf{Ad}_{\xbf{B}}<< \obf{\Omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} \\
    @A\hat{\ }AA @AA\hat{\ }A\\
    \fg{\omega}=\xbf{B}\fg{\Omega} \in\R^3 @<\xbf{B}<< \fg{\Omega}\in \R^3
  \end{CD}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, with the last release of LaTeX (2020-10-01), you can replace the three lines of code from `\begingroup` to `}` with

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{CD}{\mathcode`@="8000\relax}
```

though this is less appealing to me.

[image]

With `tikz-cd`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand\xbf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\fg[1]{#1}
\newcommand\obf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\R{{R}}

\begin{document}

Diagram:
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzcd}
  \obf{\omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} &
  \obf{\Omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} \arrow[l,"\xbf{Ad}_{\xbf{B}}"']
  \\
  \fg{\omega}=\xbf{B}\fg{\Omega} \in\R^3  \arrow[u,"\hat{\ }"] &
  \fg{\Omega}\in \R^3 \arrow[l,"\xbf{B}"'] \arrow[u,"\hat{\ }"]
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work again if you reset the mathcode of @:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand\xbf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\fg[1]{#1}
\newcommand\obf[1]{#1}
\newcommand\R{{R}}
\begin{document}


Diagram:
  \begin{equation*}\mathcode`\@="8000
  \begin{CD}
    \obf{\omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} @<\xbf{Ad}_{\xbf{B}}<< \obf{\Omega} \in \R^{3\times 3} \\
    @A\hat{\ }AA @AA\hat{\ }A\\
    \fg{\omega}=\xbf{B}\fg{\Omega} \in\R^3 @<\xbf{B}<< \fg{\Omega}\in \R^3
  \end{CD}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd probably suggest ``\AtBeginEnvironment{CD}{\mathcode`@="8000 }``